# jquery image rotator

Tags: jquery, rotator

I have the following jQuery banner rotator script and I'd like to change it a bit so that the banners rotate every X seconds even if the user doensn't click on the prev/next buttons. The current code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var active_banner_index = 0;

    function banner_next(direction) {
        var banners = $(".banner-content");
        if( banners.length ) {
            var curr = $(banners[active_banner_index]);
            active_banner_index+=direction;
            if( active_banner_index>=banners.length )
                active_banner_index = 0;
            if( active_banner_index<0 )
                active_banner_index = banners.length-1;
            next = $(banners[active_banner_index]);
            curr.fadeOut(1000, 
                function() {
                    next.fadeIn(500);
                }
                );
        }       
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tbl = $("#mega-hot-deal-666");
        var tag_left = $("#hot-deal-arrow-left");
        var tag_right = $("#hot-deal-arrow-right");

        var banners = $(".banner-content");
        if( banners.length ) {
            $(banners[0]).show();
        }

        pos = tbl.position();
        tag_left.css('z-index',100);
        tag_left.css({ 
                            position: "absolute",
                top: pos.top+67, left: pos.left-37,
                cursor: "pointer"
            });
        tag_right.css('z-index',6);
        tag_right.css({ 
                            position: "absolute",
                top: pos.top+67, left: pos.left+tbl.width()-26,
                cursor: "pointer" 
            });
    active_banner_index = 0;
        tag_left.click( function(){ banner_next(-1); } );
        tag_right.click( function(){ banner_next(1); } );
    });

</script>
```

What code would I have to add in order to make the banners rotate by themselves, without waiting for the user to click on the buttons?

Comment: Why not use the jquery cycle plugin? the functionality you want already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` to periodically call the progress function.  You also may want to pause it when the user hovers over the banner.  Here's the code you would need:

```
$(function(){
    var delay = 4000,
        int;

    // Set interval to progress
    int = setInterval(function(){
        banner_next(1);
    }, delay);

    // OPTIONAL: Pause when hovering over the banner
    $(".banner-content").hover(function(){
        clearInterval(int);
    }, function(){
        int = setInterval(function(){
            banner_next(1);
        }, delay);
    });
});
```

Reference for learning: [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) and [window.clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)

Comment: I find that this method sometimes means that the slide changes as soon as the user leaves the area, which can be a bit jarring. I'd suggest setting the interval as a variable and then clearing it on mouseenter and re-setting it again on mouseleave. This way, the delay after your mouse leaves the area is always the same.

Comment: @ N Rohler: Thanks, so I just added your script below mine but nothing happened. Should I call the function on some event, perhaps on document.ready?

Comment: @bikey77: This code is being called on `document.ready()` - see [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Add some `console.log` values and debug it via the JS console.